# Register a sidebar in a Wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, register-sidebar

We have developed a Wordpress plugin to create a reservation engine. We use a shortcode to build the checkout process. This shortcode creates html. We would like to define a sidebar in this generated html so the plugin users can append some content regarding the reservation information.

Is it not a bad practice to add a sidebar to allow the plugin users to customize it?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with registering a sidebar via plugin. You do it the same way as registering via theme:

```php
add_action( 'widgets_init', function() {
  register_sidebar([
    'name' => 'Your Sidebar',
    'id'   => 'your-sidebar',
  ] );
} );
```

Comment: Thanks @hrsetyono, then I can use it if we have the plugin published in the Wordpress directory?

Answer (score -1):

As @hrsetyono said, plugins can register anything themes can, including widget sidebars.

However, we would not recommend using an anonymous closure function, as this cannot be removed by other plugins - instead make it using a public function ( of hooking to a public class method is also fine ).

```
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpse_381433_widget', 10 );

function wpse_381433_widget(){
  register_sidebar([
    'name' => 'Your Sidebar',
    'id'   => 'your-sidebar',
  ]);
};
```

Also note that you should try to add filters to all values that others may want to manipulate using `apply_filters` - this gives other plugins a clean route in to change values without needed to change your plugin code.

For example:

```
// assign variable value ##
$number = 10;

// allow value to be filtered ##
$number = apply_filters( 'plugin/function/variable', $number );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/